# Open an HTML select tag after one option has been selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have an HTML select tag like this:

```
<select name="since_date">
    <option value="<?php $sixmonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 months')); echo $sixmonths; ?>">6 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $fivemonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 months')); echo $fivemonths; ?>">5 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $fourmonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-4 months')); echo $fourmonths; ?>">4 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $threemonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months')); echo $threemonths; ?>">3 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $twomonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 months')); echo $twomonths; ?>">2 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $onemonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month')); echo $onemonth; ?>">1 month</option>
</select>
```

And I want when for example 4 months is selected a new select tag to appear like this one:

```
<select name="until_date_4months">
    <option value="<?php $threemonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months')); echo $threemonths; ?>">3 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $twomonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 months')); echo $twomonths; ?>">2 months</option>
    <option value="<?php $onemonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month')); echo $onemonth; ?>">1 month</option>
    <option value="<?php $now = date('Y-m-d'); echo $now; ?>">Now</option>
</select>
```

Every time a period is chosen (Ex. 6 months, 5 months) a new select must appear with options lower than the selected one plus a new option "Now" like above. How is this possible? What is the approach? I want to use these information with a submit button. (Send with JQuery a GET request to a specific PHP file <- this I know how to handle). 
I can for example use JavaScript like this:

```
function sinceDateValue(selection) {
    if (selection.value == "<?php $fourmonths = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-4 months')); echo $fourmonths; ?>") {
        document.getElementbyId(until_date_4months).style.display = "block"
    }
}
```

and use for the second submit `id="until_date_4months"` and `style="display: none;"`. Also for the first submit `onchange="testValue(this);` but this will just show the submit and I want to send only two information with the form: since_date and until_date...

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? You show us your code, we'll show you ours.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will update the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the options dynamically using a loop:

```
<?php for ($i = 6; $i >= 0; $i--) { ?> 
  <option value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' . $i . ' months')); ?>">
    <?php echo ($i == 0) ? 'Now' : $i . ' months'; ?>
  </option>
<?php } ?>
```

As for the jQuery, you can grab the elements based on the one selected, and populate your select box with those:

```
$('select[name="since_date"]').on('change', function() {
  var newOpts = $('option:selected', this).nextAll().clone();
  $(newOpts).show().appendTo('#example');   
});
```

#### [Here's a complete example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Exa/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it creates the options dynamically like I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do smomething like this, all you need to do is set the right values of the options.

```
$("#one").change(function(){
    var htmlOf2 = "", d;
    for(var i=1;i<parseInt($(this).find("option:selected").text()) + 1;i++)
   {
       d = new Date();
       d = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + (i * -1));
       // This sets the right month, but is not set as a value yet. I don't know what format you want

       htmlOf2 += "<option value=''>" + (i + " months") + "</option>";
   }
   htmlOf2 += "<option>NOW</option>";
   $("#two").html(htmlOf2);
}).trigger("change");
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qaw7/1/